# How to correctly solve browser Cache With Gulp-Rev and Gulp-Rev-Collector so that my index.html file is updated

Tags: angular, caching, deployment, gulp, systemjs

I am building an angular2 project using systemJS. I use Gulp to deploy.

I want to avoid making my users click on ( Cntl + R ) to get rid of the cached css files.

To do that, I wanted to make file revision using Gulp.

Knowing that all I need, is changing a css file for the moment. so I am using :

- *gulp-rev* , to rename my files and to create my manifest.json
- *gulp-rev-collector* , to replace these files name from where we call them using our manifest
- *rev-del*, to delete the old files.

knowing that my css file is under a folder named : public. and my index.html is also under public/.

```
    gulp.task("revision:rename", function () {
     return gulp.src(["public/*.css"])
     .pipe(rev())
     // .pipe(revDel())
     .pipe(gulp.dest('public'))
     .pipe(rev.manifest())
     .pipe(gulp.dest("public"))
    });

   gulp.task("revision:updateReferences", ["revision:rename"], function () {
      gulp.src(["public/rev-manifest.json","public/*.css"])
      .pipe(collect({
          replaceReved: true,
          dirReplacements: {
              'css': 'public'
          }
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("public"))
   });
```

Calling these functions, I get correctly css files renamed, and a correct manifest.json. 
But I got two problems,

1. The collector doesnt replace my html file. And I don't know how to deal with that
2. The rev-del, makes an error  when I use it ( I commented it for the moment )

Any help will be appreciated ! 
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

1) For the delete part:

You can also use this lib
const revDelete = require('gulp-rev-delete-original');

and call it like ".pipe(revDelete())" after calling .pipe(rev())

2) For the reference part (update new hash references):

I use gulp-rev-replace lib

const revReplace = require('gulp-rev-replace');
and call it like ".pipe(revReplace())" after ".pipe(revDelete())"

I see that you found a solution, but, just showing an alternative, maybe it's useful in the future.

Comment: Could never get `rev-del` to do anything. `gulp-rev-delete-original` simply worked OOB: `.pipe(rev()).pipe(revDel())...`. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: glad it worked, thanks for the thumbs up :)

Answer (score 0):

It appeared I didn't use the collector correctly :

Now it works with :

```
gulp.task("revision:updateCSS", ["revision:rename"], function () {
   gulp.src(["public/rev-manifest.json","public/index.html"])
   .pipe(collect({
       replaceReved: false
   }))
   .pipe(gulp.dest("public"))
});
```

I posted the answer in case someone is struggling.

Comment: Did you ever get `rev-del` to do anything? Or did you change to another package?